# What is the difference betwen > and >> in Unix Command?

Tags: shell, unix, echo

Here is the echo command.

`echo "cat $PATH/$filename.csvtemp > $PATH/$filename.csv" >> $LOG_PATH/$filename.log`

I need to know the difference between > and >>

Answer (score 2):

The redirection operator `>>` opens the file where output is being redirected in **APPEND** mode, whereas `>` opens the file in write mode (existing content if any, will be overwritten)